# Why are values inside list changing (Python)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, append

I created a list called database and appended 'person' to it. When the values in person change from the for loop it keeps changing the values inside the array as well. The last value in 'reader_data' ends up being repeating 'row' times. I'd like to know why this happens and how can I prevent it from changing.

```
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as data_file:
        reader_data = csv.reader(data_file)
        headers = next(reader_data)

        database = []
        person = {}

        for row in reader_data:
            for i, value in list(enumerate(row)):
                print(database)
                if (i == 0):
                    person[headers[i]] = value
                else:
                    person[headers[i]] = int(value)

            database.append(person)
        print(database)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `database` list has many references to the *same* `person` dictionary. To avoid this, append unique dictionaries by creating the `person` variable within the first loop. Note also that variables declared within a with/as block are not locally scoped to that block. This means the rest of your code can unindent a level.

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as data_file:
    reader_data = csv.reader(data_file)
    headers = next(reader_data)

database = []

for row in reader_data:
    person = {}
    for i, value in list(enumerate(row)):
        print(database)
        if (i == 0):
            person[headers[i]] = value
        else:
            person[headers[i]] = int(value)

    database.append(person)
print(database)
```

If you didn't need the `print` within the loop, you *could* express the construction of `database` with list and dictionary comprehensions.

```
database = [
  {
    headers[i]: (value if i == 0 else int(value))
    for i, value in enumerate(row)
  }
  for row in reader_data
]
```

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if you feel it's answered your question.

Comment: Please help to keep the site organized by helping to close obviously duplicate questions as duplicates. This is one of the most common Python "gotchas".